# Not able to execute methods of two different class in one other class

Tags: java, debugging, inheritance

I am not able to call two different methods of two different class in other class one method has been executed successfully but next one couldn't be executed.

```
public class Class1 extends Classn {
    @Test
    public void Method1 () {
        // method detailing...
    }
}

public class Class2 extends Classn {
    @Test
    public void Method2 () {
        // method detailing...
    }
}

public class Class3 extends Class1 {
    @Test
    public void Method3() { 
        Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
        Class1.Method1();
        Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
        cs2.Method2();
    }
}
```

SO here **Method2** is **not getting executed** after *Method1* in *Class3*. Please any anybody tell what I missed here.

Comment: Please ident your code, it is far more readable then.

Comment: You say "**is not getting executed**", what does that mean? Does your code run straight through but the method is simply not called? Or does it not compile or crash, then please also provide the error messages. Besides that, if you truly got that think running **without compilation errors** then it looks like the bug is not inside the code you have posted, please show us more.

Comment: @Zabuza Yeah Method2() has not been called after Method1() executed

Comment: The bug is not inside the code you show us (provided you have **fixed the compiler errors**). Here is an **equivalent version** of your code with the compile error fixes @DebanjanB suggests in his answer: https://pastebin.com/Pbpk8mdy.
The output is `Method A[newline]Method B`, the second method gets called, I have tested it, no problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

if assertion is being failed at Class1.Method1(); then next line will not execute
hence below lines are not getting executed.

```
Class1.Method1(); //here should not be any assertion error
Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
cs2.Method2();
```

Comment: But Method1() has been executed successfully. then not executed for next line

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

First of all your code won't compile because in `Class3` class you are trying to access `Method1()` from `Class1` directly. As `Method1()` is non-static so it will show `Compilation Errors`

Solution: There are 2 solutions.

1. Either you access `Method1()` from `Class1` through object `cs1` of `Class1` Class as follows:

   ```
   @Test
   public void Method3()
   { 
       Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
       cs1.Method1();
       Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
       cs2.Method2();
   }
   ```
2. Else you have to declare `Method1()` in `Class1` as `static` to access `Method1()` directly as follows:

   ```
   @Test
   public static void Method1 ()
   {
       System.out.println("Within Child : Class1");
   }
   ```

   Then you can access the `Method1()` of `Class1` directly as follows:

   ```
   @Test
   public void Method3()
   { 
       Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
       Class1.Method1();
       Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
       cs2.Method2();
   }
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Here I missed in my code. I have used @Test in my two methods of class1 and class2 so due to this in class3 my second method was not called. Here I did for this and now it is working fine.

```
public class Class1 extends Classn {
    @Test <@Test removed from here>
    public void Method1 () {
        // method detailing...
    }
}

public class Class2 extends Classn {
    @Test <@Test removed from here>
    public void Method2 () {
        // method detailing...
    }
}

public class Class3 extends Class1 {
    @Test
    public void Method3() { 
        Class1 cs1 = new Class1();
        Cs1.Method1(); <Here i did typo mistake in my question>
        Class2 cs2 = new Class2();
        cs2.Method2();
    }
}
```